# Is "unto" always interchangeable with "to"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, prepositions

The word *unto* often shows up in the Bible, and I am curious to know whether it can always be replaced with the more familiar preposition *to*, while staying grammatical and making sense.

Take this example.

> And the Lord spoke to Moses and Aaron, and he gave them a charge unto the children of Israel, and unto Pharao the king of Egypt, that they should bring forth the children of Israel out of the land of Egypt. ([Exodus 6:13 Douay-Rheims](http://www.drbo.org/chapter/02006.htm))

Would the sentence still be grammatical if *unto* were replaced with *to*? Would it have the same meaning? Would it read as well?

One point worth mentioning is that, in the verse above, *unto* creates a more iambic rhythm in the sentence. Could this be a reason why it was used so much?

Comment: What research have you done?  Also your ending question has got to be primarily opinion based.

Comment: @Jim I checked two dictionaries, [m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unto) and [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unto). Although they each say a lot, neither of them satisfactorily answers the three questions I pose.

Comment: As far as grammar is concerned, absolutely any two words that are the same part of speech are interchangeable in absolutely any sentence. It is quite obvious that the result will always be grammatical, though most of the time it will be entirely nonsensical. Colorless green ideas sleep furiously. So you can't be asking about grammar alone. But if we drag meaning into this, then absolutely no two words are always interchangeable. No two words at all. In no language at all. That's why they are two words and not one. Again, this is obvious. So what exactly is the question here?

Comment: @RegDwigнt You make some good points — but what I am really asking is whether "unto", in this context, has some nuance that differentiates it from "to", and what that nuance is. For example, [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unto) has this to say about it: "used as a function word to indicate reference or concern". Is there more to this train of thought?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is unanswerable as it  mixes apples (the English of the King James Bible) with oranges (contemporary English).

Answer (score 1):

The origins of the preposition [**"unto"**](https://www.google.com/search?q=origin%20of%20unto&oq=origin%20of%20unto&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2028j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) come from **"until"** [(see link)](https://www.google.com/search?q=origin%20of%20unto&oq=origin%20of%20unto&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2028j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and technically it does just mean, [**"to"**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/unto). So, theoretically you *could* replace *"to"* with *"unto"* and get the same meaning by that measure.

However, it will sound very unidiomatic, it will sound archaic (if that is your intent then fine), and it might sound pretentious or pedantic.

---

I would not consider this to be an *important word* in the English language today simply because it's classified as archaic.

Comment: Sometimes it means until, and sometimes it means to.  They're not the same.  "Be thou faithful unto death, and I will give the a crown of life."